# Core Bluetooth immediate disconnect Peripheral after connected

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-bluetooth

In core bluetooth, after connecting to  a device , it gets automatically disconnected after 5 to 10 seconds. Its gives error something like this:
Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=7 "The specified device has disconnected from us." 
It just started showing suddenly. What could be the reason and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be two issues: either a release problem or firmware problem. For the first, ensure that you are retaining the peripheral after connection. Do this by assigning it to a strong CBPeripheral property or add it to a strong array. The second problem would involve issues with your firmware expecting a certain command to be read/written after connection which you are not sending. Assuming this firmware was written by someone else, developers add in extra security checks like this to prevent developers from using their peripherals for other purposes. If it is your own firmware, I suggest consulting your chip manufacturer's starter kit.